# Find the original expenses if the expenses have been reduced to $7.5‰$ of its original

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The expenses of a plant are reduced to $7.5‰$ of its original, (‰-is promile i.e., $2‰,=2/1000$) and are now $4255$ euro. Find the original expenses, before they decreased.

My attempt:

$S=\frac{1000i}{p}=\frac{1000\cdot 4255}{7.5}=567333,33 $ but I do not know a good acting. Hope you will help me. Thanks.

Comment: 4255/0.0075 = 567333.333333

Comment: I correct, I was wrong during the writing

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, and it is written down exactly, I think that should be the correct answer. But detail is very important. 'Reduced to' and 'Reduced with/by' have very different results. I also don't understand what your question is. A correct answer or a good explanation.

Comment: The costs of a shop are reduced to 7.5‰, and are now 4255 euro. Costs required to set as there were shop early, ie before the reduced costs. 
I hope that now maybe it is better explained